# How to compute whether the proportion of a group changes without allocating new memory?

Tags: memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose you are given the `quantity, price, item ID, group ID` for distinct items. Find the proportional value of each group, where proportional value is defined as the product sum of quantity and price of all items within that group.

Here's an example, suppose you're given

```
quantity. price  item ID  group ID
1,        100,   A        0
1,        25,    B        1
1,        25,    C        1
```

Proportional value for group 0 is `1 * 100 / (1 * 100 + 1 * 25 + 1 * 25) = 2/3` and 1/3 for group 1.

The code I wrote is something like this (I'm going to use `Python` for simplicity):

```
# assume inputs is a list of 4-tuples where each 4-tuple contains quantity, price, item ID, group ID
def compute_proportions(inputs):
    product_sum = {}

    # Calculate the product sum for each group_id
    for input_data in inputs:
        group_id = input_data[3]
        if group_id not in product_sum:
            product_sum[group_id] = 0
        product_sum[group_id] += input_data[0] * input_data[1]

    # Calculate the total sum of product sums
    total_sum = sum(product_sum.values())

    # Calculate proportions for each group_id
    proportions = {}
    for group_id, group_sum in product_sum.items():
        proportions[group_id] = group_sum / total_sum

    return proportions
```

Simple enough. But then, the follow up question was "Suppose the price of some item changes, return whether each group's proportion increases, but you can't allocate memory while doing this."

I asked if I have access to the original inputs and he said no and apparently I only have access to the return value (proportions) of the previous function.

I couldn't figure this out before time run out and the interviewer said this is apparently some tricky problem that most people can't solve but never told me what he was looking for.

How does one solve this problem without allocating additional memory?